# find the characteristic polynomial of $T_{|W }.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F := \mathbb{R}$, let $V$ be the space of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $T: V \to V$ be the operator sending $f$ to $xf'$
, where $f'$is the derivative of $f$. Let $W$ be the $T-$cyclic subspace of $V$ generated by $x^2 + 1$. Compute the characteristic polynomial of $T_{|W }.$

**My attempt** : It is clear to me that  $W$ is  a  $T$ invariant subspace of  $V$

and $W= \operatorname{span} \{x^2+1, 2x^2\} $

The problem is that I do not know how to find  the characteristic polynomial of $T_{|W }.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$T(x^2+1)=2x^2 \qquad T(2x^2)=4x^2.$$
So, $W$ has $\{x^2+1,2x^2\}$ as a basis (you already have that).

Thus the matrix for $T$ with respect to the basis you have for $W$ is given by
$$[T]=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.$$
This implies that the characteristic polynomial of $T|_{W}$ is $\lambda^2-2\lambda$

Comment: I am not getting   why  is $[T]=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.$? I think  $[T]=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.$.

Comment: $T(x^2+1)=0.(x^2+1)  +1 .2x^2$  and $T(2x^2)=0.(x^2+1) + 2.(2x^2)$

Comment: @jasmine Let $\{v_1,v_2\}=\{x^2+1,2x^2\}$, then $T(v_1)=v_2=0.v_1+1.v_2$ and $T(v_2)=2v_2=0.v_1+2.v_2$. Thus the "columns" of $[T]$ are $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: okay @Anurag I thought  we should take row